# What is the difference between {{ }} and {!! !!} in laravel blade files?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In the laravel framework we can use blade to add PHP code in html file.
We are using both `{{ }}` and `{!! !!}` syntax in blade files of Laravel. 
What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

> [Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#displaying-data)

If you pass data from your Controller to a View with some HTML styling like:

```
$first = "<b>Narendra Sisodia</b>";
```

And it is accessed, within Blade, with `{{ $first }}` then the output'll be:

```
<b>Narendra Sisodia</b>
```

But if it is accessed with `{!! $first !!}` then the output'll be:

**Narendra Sisodia**

Comment: Highly impressive solution and given example, thanks Narendrasingh Sisodia :)

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want the data to be escaped then use `{!! !!}` else use `{{ }}`.

Answer (score 9):

To escape data use

```
{{ $data }}
```

If you don't want the data to be escaped use below

```
{!! $data !!}
```

Answer (score 7):

**from the documentation:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade

By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
Hello, {!! $name !!}.
```

Answer (score 3):

Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks.

You can see more here:https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel `{{ }}` should pass data as plain text with HTML escaping while `{!! !!}` pass data as content as-is, without any HTML escaping.

**For e.g:** I have a `$status = '<b>Active Status</b>';` variable which stores HTML content as a data.

Now if I write this data as `{{ $status }}` Then it will return as a `plain text`.

Expected Output is:

```
<b>Active Status</b>
```

But if I write this data as `{!! $status !!}` then it will return as `HTML` code.

Expected Output is: