# URL::to() for getting a resource route

Tags: php, laravel

For my `useController.php` page i have created `three views inside a folder called users,and they are--`

```
1.index.blade  2.create.blade  3.store.blade
```

i have ***another form.blade outside of the users folder and i want to access one of the resource route from my form.blade***.But as i attached the route to an anchor tag with `URL::to()` method ,it is not generating a proper route.And if i try to click the link it sends me to

> Access forbidden,error 403

And if i `view source` the form.blade page i see that no proper url is generated for the anchor tag...

[image]

***from.blade.php :***

```
 <span style='color:red'>Not signed up yet !!! </span><a href="{{URL::to('user/create')">register</a>
  <h2 style='color:purple;'>login </h2>
   {!!Form::open(array('url'=>'user')) !!}

   {!!Form::label('name','Your name')!!}
   {!!Form::text('name','',array('placeholder'=>'put your name here'))!!}

    {!!Form::label('password','password')!!}
    {!!Form::password('password')!!}

    {!!Form::submit('Login')!!}
    {!!Form::close()!!}
```

Comment: On a side note, I would look into [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes) for the future `route('user.create')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="{{url('user/create')}}">register</a>
```

you forget use `}}`

Comment: thanks...i am new to laravel..i have a question..whats the difference between " {!!" and "{{".. i have seen that people use both of them

Comment: @AL-zami http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030977/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-laravel-blade-files/35031303#35031303

Comment: Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

This should be work.

```
<a href="{{url('user/create')}}">register</a>
```