# How to display HTML tag passed as object value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on laravel, where I am passing array of objects like this to my view-

[image]

Now problem is when I am displaying the data it's showing the html part as text content,which is problematic to generate html.is there any built in php function that converts to HTML?

Coming in this way -

[image]

Any idea to solve is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between {{ }} and {!! !!} in laravel blade files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030977/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-laravel-blade-files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5: Display HTML with Blade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade)

Answer (score 9):

If you are using blade you should do it this way:

```
{!! $htmlString !!}
```

It will render raw html.

Comment: Thanks it works,I was looking for any older post,@uchiha quickly helped me to save my time.