# html class not found in laravel template

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

This is my main.blade.php file

```
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>


        <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         {{ HTML::script('js/funciones.js') }}//the html class is not found
    </body>
</html>
```

when i try to execute the file on the serve i get this error

```
FatalErrorException in a17fd89ebbf444a204167f09a50ec2b0fd529cbe.php line 24: Class 'HTML' not found
```

But I've followed the instrutions to add laravell collective library , on this url https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html,everything seems correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `{{ HTML::script('js/funciones.js') }}` with `{!! HTML::script('js/funciones.js') !!}` and that should do it. For more information what is difference between `{{ }}` and `{!! !!}` check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030977/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-laravel-blade-files).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: You have `'Html'      => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class` in your app.php?

Comment: `'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class` on the aliases array

Comment: And you have provider also?

Comment: yes `Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class` on providers array

Comment: change `'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class ` to capital in aliases `HTML `

Comment: Glad to help you :)