# Laravel blade "{{ command }}" not working correctly

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have this weird problem with my Laravel 5.5 version... I created the auth views using

php artisan make:auth

This command created the views controllers and everything I need to lets get stared to work. But I'm having this visualization problem

[image]

As you can see on the register view I have this problem.

The real thing is that "{{ any_command }}" is printing the code that its supose to generate instead of interprating like part of the code. But if I use {!! any_command !!} instead it seems to work propertly. What can happend to my laravel is screwed up. It has nothing to be with the artisan auth method, because I tried to create a new form (using laravel collective form helper) and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

`{{ }}` will escape all data before printing. So, if you write any HTML tag inside, it will be escaped and printed as is. Just like your example.

`{!! !!}` will print unescaped data. This will print the tags correctly, but you have to take care where you use it, because someone could inject unwanted data there.

So, in your case, you should use `{!! !!}`.

Please, refer to this question: [What is the difference between {{ }} and {!! !!} in laravel blade files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030977/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-laravel-blade-files)

Comment: But in other Laravel projects I been using by example {{Form::open('...')}} and works correctly ... now it just print the form tag as plain text. It's not suppose to works that way.

Comment: Go to the website of Laravel Collective and check the `Opening a Form` section. You will see that {!! !!} is used. Check if the project you used it is an old project or has another version of this library. Ref: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html