# Document of Laravel about strange syntax

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I saw this in the template:

```
<span class="name">{!! test() !!}</span>
```

Please help to show me a document of this syntax. 
I searched and I didn't know **Laravel** allow this syntax.

Comment: this syntax used for displaying unescaped data. See this link  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between {{ }} and {!! !!} in laravel blade files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030977/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-laravel-blade-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
{!! $name !!}
```

That is, if I pass data through a variable named `name` to the view and `{{ $name }}` is used to display it, It will display as it passed because statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function to prevent XSS attacks. For example,

```
return view('welcome')->with('name','<script>alert("Hai");</script>');
```

is used to return view with data in variable named `name` and

```
<div class="title m-b-md">
    {{$name}}
</div>
```

is used to disply my data. The output will be
[image]

And if I use

```
<div class="title m-b-md">
    {!!$name!!}
</div>
```

to display the data, The output will be
[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much for your detail answer :)

Answer (score 1):

That's just [unescaped data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data):

> **Displaying Unescaped Data**
>   By default, Blade {{ }} statements are
>   automatically sent through PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent
>   XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use
>   the following syntax:
>
> ```
> Hello, {!! $name !!}.
> ```

Comment: Thanks you :D I omitted it