# Can not html entity decode of string in laravel5 blade view

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, htmldecode

I use Php7.0 and Laravel 5.0 and want to initiate a var in javascript on blade page.

But html_entity_decode function can not decode the special chars.

```
userName =  "{{ html_entity_decode($user->name) }}"
console.log(userName);
```

I would like to see `" ' < >` but it gives me `&quot; &#039; &lt; &gt;`

While checkin in db I can see correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030977/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-laravel-blade-files, https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#displaying-data

Comment: Isn't it `{!! html_entity_decode($user->name) !!}`??

Comment: Doesn't laravel decode strings between braces automatically as of Laravel 5+?

Comment: I tried to {!! but javascript gives error. Because I want to assign username to javascript var.

Comment: Please get out of the habit of giving useless statements like _“but javascript gives error”_. **Quote error messages verbatim**, and also show the code that causes them (in this case the client-side code that whatever you put into your template produced, as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some quick testing. And the following example works on my side;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userName = {!! json_encode($user->name) !!};
    console.log(userName);
</script>
```

When I check my console, the `userName` is displayed properly.